# Ubuntu 19.10 closes all apps on screen lock

Tags: gnome, network-manager, suspend, 19.10

If i let my pc idle out, on opening again all the applications are killed.

i tried:

> sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -iE "power|sleep|shutdown"

and this is what pops up.

[system log for power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epOlt.png)

> Feb  2 14:01:11 banana NetworkManager[878]:   [1580632271.5865] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
>
> Feb  2 14:01:11 banana NetworkManager[878]:   [1580632271.5866] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
>
> Feb  2 14:01:13 banana gnome-shell[10606]: Error setting property 'Powered' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Blocked: Blocked through rfkill (g-io-error-quark, 36)
>
> Feb  2 14:02:30 banana gnome-shell[12236]: Error setting property 'Powered' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Blocked: Blocked through rfkill (g-io-error-quark, 36)
>
> Feb  2 14:11:03 banana gnome-shell[13371]: Error setting property 'Powered' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Blocked: Blocked through rfkill (g-io-error-quark, 36)

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it doesn't look like this issue will be resolved in 19.10 I just moved on to 20.04 and haven't yet run into the same issue.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue some digging has revealed that gnome-shell is segfaulting in a similar fashion to that which is reported [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249359) and [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/63886).

This seems to be a bug in gnome-shell which by the sound of the Arch Linux forum/bugtracker was fixed but may not have made it into Ubuntu.